# 2003 Yamaha 650 V Star won't start

Tags: motorcycle, starting, yamaha

My grand baby got on my bike playing and I'm guessing he flooded it.

I went and bought new plugs because the old ones were in bad shape, it ran good. I had just got home from riding it that same day, so I'm actually stumped on this one, if anyone can help out in solving this I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Is your bike carb'd or fuel injected?

Comment: This is a bit unclear. So, did your grandchild mess with the bike before or after you changed the plugs and rode it? When you say "won't start", do you mean it turns over but won't fire or it does nothing when you press the start button? More details will help us answer accurately.

Answer (score 2):

**Your bike does NOT have an accelerator pump**

Many carburetor based motorcycles do NOT come with accelerator pumps.  An accelerator pump will squirt fuel into the intake when the throttle is used.  Whether the bike is on or off.

[Here is a link](http://www.bikebandit.com/oem-parts/2003-yamaha-v-star-classic-650-xvs650ar/o/m145599#sch261792) to the parts assembly for the fuel system of your bike and an image.

[image]

Notice that there is not piston to pump fuel as a component of the assembly.  You can rule out that your bike was flooded by the grand child.

**Possible Causes**

- You may not have spark.  Test for spark by taking your spark plug out of the head and putting it on the high tension lead as normal.  Make sure the bottom part of the spark plug is grounded on your engine.   Turn the bike over as if your were going to start it.  Check the plug gap while the bike turns over and validate that you have spark.  You will see it.  Make sure the gap is shaded, in bright sunlight it may appear you don't have one.  If you do, you can rule out the spark plug, coils and wiring that is associated with it.
- If you do not have spark and the insulator of the spark plug is black, you may have a rich condition and you have fouled your plugs.  You can clean them with carburetor cleaner and an old toothbrush.
- Check your choke.  If the you happened to ride the bike with choke on you may have fouled your plugs.  As well, if it's warm, you may not be able to start the bike due to the choke.  Validate the choke setting.

Those are few things for you to investigate.  If you discover more information, please post to your question and additional ideas can be derived from the data you have gathered attempting to troubleshoot.

Best of luck.

Comment: Great answer.  I might add that even if your choke was in the wrong position while the bike was running, if there are no deposits on the plug, that shouldn't be the source of your problems.

Comment: @anonymous2  Good point!